# PHP PDO Error in Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having some issues with PDO.  First issue is that in my connection string, I cannot use variables defined in another file (tried include & require). It gives me an error and shows the connectionstring having the variable name instead of the value (yes, single and double quotes were tried).

Second issue and more pressing is that I am getting an error when trying to validate a login.  I had it working with the old mysqli, so I know that the html is valid, just not the new logic.  Attached is the function I am using:

```
function validateuser($un, $em)
{
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XX", 'aa', 'bb', array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT AcctType FROM usr WHERE LOGIN_ID=? or CONTACT_EMAIL=?;");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            $un,
            $em
        ));
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    catch(exception $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

the exact error i get is:

```
Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 ' in db_backend.php:110 Stack trace: #0 db_backend.php(110): PDO->query('SELECT AcctType...') #1 newuser.php(42): validateuser('Nefer', 'neferitous@blah...') #2 {main}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This might be a clue: [Error 2031](http://www.briandunning.com/errors/656)

Comment: According to this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#97531 something is wrong with your data that is being bound.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here is my final code to make this part of the PDO statement work:

```
function validateuser($un, $em) {
    try {
        $db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db",
            'id',
            'pass',
            array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
        );
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ACCTTYPE FROM users WHERE LOGIN_ID=? or CONTACT_EMAIL=?;");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $un, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $em, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        return $result["ACCTTYPE"];
    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to bind parameters, you need to use a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and not a query.

Try the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT AcctType FROM usr WHERE LOGIN_ID=? or CONTACT_EMAIL=?;");
$stmt->execute(array(
    $un,
    $em
));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped me and I will mark it as answer.  It was more than this though. I had to use binding on each variable for it to work and specify the data type. I am used to doing this with vb and c# and am surprised that it is this complex here. I will post my final code for others so that it may hopefully be of help to somebody else.

Comment: @shoretek Great! Thanks for posting the solution. Good luck on your journey with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, I'm pretty sure you could break the string and concatenate the variables in:

```
PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname, $user, $pass,
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I had tried it earlier and just confirmed it. For some reason, I am not picking up variables from another file. Not sure what code to post to show that I am referring to, but will try:  in my file called config01.php I am declaring $db_host, $db_name and setting them to localhost and usertable respectively.  from the PDO file (which is in the same folder as the config01 file), I am using include('config01.php');. If you need more, let me know. Thank you for your input!